# Using variable type variables as array names in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a dynamic menu in my web, in which only some pages from each section will appear.

The code I wrote was:

```
$menulist=array();

$menulist[1]='file1%#16';

$menulist[2]='file2%#9';

$menulist[3]='file3%#19';

$menulist[4]='file4%#8';

$menulist[5]='file5%#13';

$menulist[6]='file6%#14';

$menulist[7]='file7%#10';

$menulist[8]='file8%#23';

$menulist[9]='file9%#19';

$menulist[10]='file10%#18';

$menulist[11]='file11%#12';

function actualizaciones($matriz)

{

$linea=explode("%#",$matriz);

echo '&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="first_chunk_of_URL'.$linea[0].'middle_chunk_of_url'.$linea[1].'last_chunk_of_URL"&gt;'.${$linea[0]}[$linea[1]].'&lt;/li&gt;;

}

echo '&lt;ul&gt;';

array_walk($menulist,'actualizaciones');

echo '&lt;/ul&gt;';
```

Every `$linea[0]` string is the name of another array (not shown in this code) which contains the text that should be in every possible link corresponding to every key passed by `$linea[1]`.

I must have done something wrong, because the hyperlinks work fine but there's no text showing on them.

Comment: please output some valid HTML code and not that encoded version. it's really hard to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question right, you're asking how to use variable variables in PHP.

This can be done using the double-dollar syntax - ie `$$linea[0]`. See the PHP manual for more info: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

But if that is what you're doing, I would say you're not writing good code: if variable variables are involved, there's almost always a better way of doing it.

Can't really offer much better assistance here without understanding more about what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you should be using subarrays rather than separate named variables for everything.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

use the simple character like below

```
echo '<li><a href="first_chunk_of_URL'.$linea[0].'middle_chunk_of_url'.$linea[1].'last_chunk_of_URL"&gt;'.${$linea[0]}[$linea[1]].'<li>';
```

and the problem in your code is

```
.'&lt;/li&gt;;

         ^^^^^

        here is the problem it should be

.'&lt;/li&gt;';
```